# Apache httpd rewrite url based on query string lookup

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string, rewritemap

I need to rewrite URL to direct request to different backend servers based on query parameter, using a text map of (queryparam servername).

I have tried the RewriteMap, RewriteRule with a prg: type and a perl script. But the query string is not visible in the lookup script.

e.g map file

```
    QS1 Server1
    QS2 Server1
    QS3 Server3
    QS4 Server4
    etc.. (about 10K entries -= mapping to about 20 backend servers)
```

If input URL is
http://myrouter.com:8080/a/b/c?query=QS2

then it should be rewritten and sent to 
http://Server1:9988/a/b/c?query=QS2  (yes with the query string)

http://myrouter.com:8080/a/b/c?query=QS4 sent to
http://Server4:9988/a/b/c?query=QS4

My current trials doesnt seem to help.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap distributeRequests "prg:/export/requestdistributor.pl"
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${distributeRequests:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}} [P]
```

I looked up [Proxy based on parameter in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645622/proxy-based-on-parameter-in-the-url)  But that is good for a limited set of lookup entries; not for the 10K query parameters mapping to 10 backend servers I am looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following link helped with how the query string can be passed into the script.

https://daryl.blog/2008/11/17/using-rewritemap-for-query-string-voodoo/

Solved.
Thanks.